# htc g1 cannot discover/connect to a 802.11 n/b/g wifi

Tags: wi-fi, htc-dream

My G1 was able to connect to a WiFi (not sure about its mode). But after I moved to a new house, I found it cannot discover/connect to the WiFi in the house, but it can discover the WiFi signal from other house.

My laptop is able to discover and connect to the WiFi in my house, so does my Galaxy P1000. I checked my WiFi setting of my router, and the WiFi mode is 802.11 n/b/g. I then checked the HTC G1 specification, and it says it supports 802.11 b/g. Do I have to change the WiFi setting of my router to b/g? I think the device should be able to detect the mode and choose the best available one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with my HTC Hero.  I never got around to fixing it but I remember reading that the router needs to be forced to stay in b/g mode.

Check this post seems to confirm that idea:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/archive/index.php/t-492536.html

Comment: Yes, I confirm that Daniel is right. I changed my router to b/g mode, and my g1 is able to discover and connect to the router. Is it a bug in g1?